# How do we initialize a std::vector in a class constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector

How do we initialize a std::vector in a class constructor in c++?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass( int p_Var1, int* p_Vector ) : Var1( p_Var1 ) //, Initialize std::vector - MyVector with p_Vector
    {
    };
    ~MyClass( void );
private:
    int Var1;
    std::vector< int > MyVector;
};
```

Comment: I what way do you want to initialize your `std::vector`? (What specific form of its constructors do you want to use?)

Comment: It depends. What do you mean by "initialize"? Against which version of C++ standard are you working?

Comment: @Mark Garcia with int* p_Vector

Comment: std::vector has various ways to initialize, and any of them can be used within the body of the constructor to initialize it. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: If you want to copy `p_Vector` just use `vector`'s copy constructor `) : myVector(*p_Vector)`

Comment: Oh really? Didn't know that. Okay, I want to take the constructor 2nd parameter (int* _pVector) and "put" it in MyVector.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821998/initialization-of-vector-in-a-constructor-c

Comment: @hmjd `p_Vector` isn't a pointer to a vector, but a pointer to the first element of a C style array.  (I presume.)  `: myVector( *p_Vector )` will create a vector whose size is determined by the first `int` in the array, initialized with 0.

Comment: @JamesKanze, oops. Dreaming and the name of the variable appears to have had quite an affect on me...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, `myVector` will be initialized, even if you do nothing,
since it has non-trivial constructors.  If you want to
initialize it given a pointer to a sequence of `int`, you'll
also have to know the length.  If you have both a pointer and
the length, you can do:

```
: myVector( pInitialValues, pInitialValues + length )
```

Alternatively (and more idiomatically), you'll let the caller do
the addition, and have the constructor take two pointers, 
a begin and an end:

```
: myVector( pBegin, pEnd )
```

(If the caller is using C++11, he can obtain these from
a C style array using `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.)

EDIT:

Just to make it perfectly clear: just an `int*` doesn't provide
enough information to do anything.  An `int*` points to the
first element of a C style array; you also need some way of
finding the end: an element count, an end pointer, etc.  In
special cases, other techniques can be used; i.e. if the C style
array contains only non-negative numbers, you could use `-1` as
a sentinal, and something like `: myVector( pVector, std::find(
pVector, NULL, -1 ) )`.  These are special cases, however.

Comment: *since it has non-trivial constructors*? Shouldn't it be *since it has default constructor*? And there is a copy constructor :)

Comment: @BЈовић Not sure exactly what should be there.  Formally, it's a non-trivial constructor which can be called with the arguments given (or a non-trivial default constructor, if no initialization is specified).  Practically, however, there are non-trivial constructors which _don't_ initialize the data members, including the compiler generated ones (e.g. if the class has virtual functions).  So while the standard might consider the member "initialized", it wouldn't be initialized by any reasonable meaning of the word.  (But `vector` has a user defined ctor which does the right thing.)